# Integrating a wordpress site with a meteor members area

Tags: javascript, wordpress, meteor

I have

- a wordpress landing site/blog on example.com
- a meteor app member area on members.example.com

This has worked very well so far - both technologies are very suited for each part.

I'd like to add some **client-side** functionality to the wordpress site that communicates with the meteor app. At the very least it should be able to retrieve log in status and username from the meteor app. Additionally I'd like to add some forms that interact with meteor data.

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a REST API to your Meteor app which exposes the data you want via HTTP Methods. GET for things like getting the user login state or username. POST to create the forms you would like. I cannot describe how to do this any better than what was said on Meteorpedia, so I will just refer you there:

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API

From there you would call the REST API from WordPress. I am by no means a WordPress expert but I do imagine there are probably a number of plugins and there is probably built in functionality in WordPress to call a REST API from the client side. If not, you could make AJAX calls using custom JavaScript or jQuery or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar setting for my app!

I also thought of ways to interact between my two sites. Basically, you would have to set up an access between Wordpress and your app's MongoDB database, and I am sorry to say, [it does not seem very likely to happen in a near future](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/suggestion-support-mongodb-hypertable-or-other-nosql-storage)...

Best thing you could have is actually going the other way (accessing Wordpress's MySQL through your Meteor app), using a package like [meteor-mysql](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql), and even that would only allow you to *read* the data in your wordpress database... but reactively! Wooo!

To my knowledge, that is the best "interaction" I can think of that you can get (without extensive hacking) so far.

Then if you are ready and willing to code your way through, you can implement calls to your meteor server using the [meteor-ddp-php client](https://github.com/zyzo/meteor-ddp-php) in your WordPress site. Just make sure your Meteor methods are safe to call.

Comment: Thank you. That would be very good to have, but in my case it's not needed: in my application, the wordpress server doesn't need to know anything about the meteor app. I'd like to communicate with the meteor server from the wp client side though. In a way, it doesn't matter that it's wordpress, but I wanted to make it clear that it's not another nodejs app.

Comment: Updated my answer with another suggestion then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load your meteor application into you wordpress blog then you could just load it in as an iFrame.

To communicate with the meteor application just build some endpoints onto the meteor application which can be used on the wordpress blog. Because meteor is reactive the changes you do with the endpoints (Probably rest since is the simples option imo) will be directly shown in the iframe.

My 2 cents